# Assign public IP to docker

Tags: docker

I have a docker container running on Linux server. I can get the response by a curl to the internal IP as below.
curl http://172.17.0.2:8080/greeting?name=jo

This Linux server's public IP is 199.231.191.106. How can I access the docker application by using this public IP?

Comment: Did you expose the port 8080 when run the container? Did you have any firewall rules to block the access? Then, you should be fine to access via http://199.231.191.106:8080/greeting?name=jo

Comment: If you need access it by default http with port 80, you can expose the port from container:8080 to localhost:80

Comment: We actually need more details on your set up to help you. I would also suggest you to edit out your public IP address ;)

Comment: I mapped the container port to default port 80 and it worked. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A docker container running a web server is likely to [EXPOSE a port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose).

You can see it by inspecting its image (or the running container directly) with

```
docker inspect --format='{{range $p, $conf := .Config.ExposedPorts}} {{$p}} {{end}}'<container>
```

When you run your container, you need to map that EXPOSE'd port to the Linux host, in order for said port to be accessible.
See [`docker run -p hostPort:containerPort`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports)

```
docker run -p 80:8080 ...
```